# How can I specifically list only user's Pages using Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I specifically list only user's **pages** using **Graph API**?

I do know that `/me/accounts` returns user's pages and apps, but it is also lists shared blog posts and other weird things for some users.

I can easily exclude apps filtering the entries that **Category** match '***Application***', but for some users I got other things that are not page neither apps.

Is there some list of all existent categories? Or all page categories (that hopefully wont change)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `type=page` to the query parameters.

To get all pages for the current user, you would use: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?type=page&access_token=user_access_token`

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts%3Ftype%3Dpage

Comment: Fantastically simple =)
How could I have not seen it on Facebook documentation? Where did you find it?

Comment: It's mentioned obscurely on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ under the "Searching" header.